# Cell click event in table layout..

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to know how to get the cell click(ex:I want to click in the 3rd colomn of the 2nd row i.e. in 2x3 cell) event in a dynamic table view.I know about row click. But I want the particular cell click..
 Is it possible in list view if list view contains rows along with colomns??

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using TableLayout dynamically you can do this thing.

```
   TableLayout table = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
   TableLayout.LayoutParams tab_lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
   table.setLayoutParams(tab_lp);

  TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

  final TextView tvProduct = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

  LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp_l3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvProduct.setLayoutParams(lp_l3);
    tvProduct.setText(product);
    tvProduct.setClickable(true);   

    row.addView(tvProduct,  new TableRow.LayoutParams(1));
    table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams());     

    tvProduct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Beers.this,BeerDetails.class);
            i.putExtra("Product_Name",tvProduct.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i);
         }
    });

    LinearLayout linearMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearmainLayout);
    linearMain.addView(table);      
    linearMain.postInvalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GridView` for this kind of UI instead of `TableLayout` or `ListView`. In GridView you can set `OnItemClickListener`. Read more about GridView [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).